# Modelling Categorical Data: Dummies or Factors?

Tags: r

I'm using a coxph-model to estimate different covariates.

One covariate in my model is a categorial variable called LOCATION, specifically a geographical one, which can have four states:

```
Boston=1

NY=2

MIAMI=3

LA=4
```

I'm really confused how the function handles categorical variables. 
Klein and Moeschberger (2005) wrote in their book "Survial Analysis.." that one should treat categorical as dummies.
Hence I would create three dummy variables: NY, MIAMI and LA, where BOSTON would be the referrence group, my model would look like that:

1. `coxph(surv(start,event)~NY+MIAMI+LA, data=FNMA)`
   ***(dummy model)***

This makes me really curious, because if this model should be correct, the function should automatically understand that Boston is the reference group in that case?

On the other hand, I once read that one could simply transform the LOCATION variable as a factor:

2. `coxph(surv(start,event)~factor(LOCATION), data=FNMA)` 
   ***(factor model)***

The 2nd model makes more sense to me honestly, but I'm really confused since the book I referenced stated that one should treat it like in 1. (Maybe the book is to old?)

***So which model is correct now?***

Thanks,

KS

Comment: I believe that as a general rule, in `R` you should use factors. Note however that if you want that order you **must** set `factor` argumet `levels = c("Boston", "NY", "Miami", "LA")`.

Answer (score 1):

They should give you the same thing (at least they do in ordinary linear regression and GLM models). If you give R a factor it will create dummies "under the hood" using your first factor level as reference level.

Your output with the factor should have the factor name listed three times, slightly modified to show you which level it refers to.